# Print specific value on JButton click

Tags: java, swing

I have a method that is called 4 times. That method returns a JPanel inside which is a JButton. I want when I click button1 to print 1, button2 to print 2 and so on. Now when I click any button it prints 4. It's like the method was called 4 times, count = 4 and each button has that 4 . How can I solve this ?

```
private int count=0;

private JPanel createPanel(){
        count++;
        JPanel app = new JPanel(true);
        app.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1);
        app.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,dHeight));
        JButton btn = createButton("Click Me");
        buttonStyle(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(e -> this.doStuff(count));
        app.add(btn);

        return app;
}

private void doStuff(int t){
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you call the `createPanel()`  4 times, your counter will be increased by 4 times. All your `doStuff()` calls passing the variable `count`,  which is a member of your class and is shared by all other members such as `doStuff()`. The `count` was increasd 4 times before and is therefore at 4. So every button will print out 4.

Quick fix:

```
private JPanel createPanel(){
        int copyCounter = count; // Copy the counter
        count++;
        JPanel app = new JPanel(true);
        app.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1);
        app.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,dHeight));
        JButton btn = createButton("Click Me");
        buttonStyle(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(e -> this.doStuff(copyCounter)); // Use copy here
        app.add(btn);

        return app;
}
```

By doing this you will create a copy of your counter within your method, this value won't be increased by future calls of `createPanel()`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. Why do you say that is dirty ? How would be the clean way ?

Comment: your are using lambda so i guess it is fine anyways but in my opinion creating a copy of a variable inside a method which is then used later on (normaly it would be gone after the method will exit), is some kind of dirty.
I removed the dirty from the post (it's just my general opinion)

Comment: What is the other way of doing this, without creating the copy of the variable ?

Comment: the variable needs to be copied either way. The way I had in mind was to create another class which extends from the actionlistener interface (just like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and pass the value to this class an store it there. Would be a bit to much of an overhead for a single print method, but is preferable in my opinion.

Comment: to make my opinion a bit more reasonable: if you are no using java 8 (lambda), and thats where my origin call came from, you would require to make the variable "copyCounter" final. Ands thats something I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Your count variable is a member of your class. Thus every call to createPanel() will increase the value of it.

doStuff prints t (the current value of count).

You have to store the value of count in an instance of JButton. Usually by extending this class to your own MyJButton class with a member variable "private int id".